# Calculate EMA for MACD with 2 lines indicator in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, charts, algorithmic-trading, indicator

I'm trying to write an indicator script that will plot the MACD with 2 lines in a practice trading tool.

At the moment, I'm following the formula which is [using the EMA formula to calculate it.](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/movingaverage.asp)

I'm able to plot the chart. But somehow my indicator result does not have the exact same result as the one on meta trader 4 or on trading view. The indicator result on these apps is exactly the same.

I think I have missed something when I try to convert from the formula to actual code. Please help me fix it. Thank you.

Here is the part that will calculate the EMA.

```
/// ==================================================================
/// ======================== calculations ============================
/// ==================================================================
public void Calculate()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Bars.Length; i++){
        if (i >= SlowEMA) {
            MACD[i] = CalculateEMA(FastEMA, i) - CalculateEMA(SlowEMA, i);
            Signal[i] = CalculateEMA_MACD(MACD, SignalEMA, i);
            Histogram[i] = MACD[i] - Signal[i];
        }
    }
}

private double CalculateEMA(int Period, int index)
{
    var currentValue = 0d;
    var currentEMA = 0d;
    var yesterdayEMA = 0d;
    var smooth = 2d;
    var multiplier = smooth / (1 + Period);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < Period; i++){
        currentValue = GetPrice(index + i - Period);
        currentEMA = (currentValue * multiplier) + (yesterdayEMA * (1 - multiplier));
        yesterdayEMA = currentEMA;
    };
    return yesterdayEMA;
}

private double CalculateEMA_MACD(double[] MACD, int Period, int index)
{
    var currentValue = 0d;
    var currentEMA = 0d;
    var yesterdayEMA = 0d;
    var smooth = 2d;
    var multiplier = smooth / (1 + Period);
    for (int i = 0; i < Period; i++){
        currentValue = MACD[index + i - Period];
        currentEMA = (currentValue * multiplier) + (yesterdayEMA * (1 - multiplier));
        yesterdayEMA = currentEMA;
    };
    return yesterdayEMA;
}

private double GetPrice(int index)
{
    Bar bar = Bars[index];
    switch (Source)
    {
        case Sources.Close:
            return bar.Close;
        case Sources.Open:
            return bar.Open;
        case Sources.High:
            return bar.High;
        case Sources.Low:
            return bar.Low;
        case Sources.MedianPrice:
            return (bar.High + bar.Low) / 2;
        case Sources.TypicalPrice:
            return (bar.High + bar.Low + bar.Close) / 3;
        case Sources.WeightedClose:
            return (bar.High + bar.Low + bar.Close + bar.Close) / 4;
    }
    throw new NotSupportedException("Unsupported price source type: " + Source);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your logic for EMA calculation is wrong. Based on your code, `yesterdayEMA` is always `0` and therefore right part of EMA equation is also `0`.

```
private double CalculateEMA(int Period, int index)
{
    ...
    var yesterdayEMA = 0D;
    ...
    currentEMA = (currentValue * multiplier) + (yesterdayEMA * (1 - multiplier));
    currentEMA = (currentValue * multiplier) + 0
    ...
}
```

You need to store `yesterdayEMA` outside of `CalculateEMA` and pass it as parameter for recursive calculation.

Answer (score 0):

0 comes true in the first cycle, but yesterday `EMA = current EMA;` It starts to take values different from 0 in the next cycle due to its equality.